# The lastest Lubuntu 16.04.6 alternate version is missing

Tags: updates, lubuntu, alternate

As you can see [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/16.04.6/release/), there isn't a Lubuntu 16.04.6 alternate ISO for download. The last is `lubuntu-16.04.1-alternate-i386.iso` (2016-07-20), while there is a `lubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386.iso` (2019-02-27). Of course, the 16.04.1 will be upgraded to the ultimate version after the updates if internet connection is present.

So, why there isn't the lastest version of the alternate installer?

How can I download (in a removable disk) and install the ultimate updates and bug fixes to an offline computer in wich I installed the 16.04.1 version?

Comment: I would suggest you install Lubuntu 18.04 regardless.  If you check https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/Lubuntu in Support (at the end) you'll note Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (being a flavor) has only 3 years of support, which ends next month (April 2019).  Only the main Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Unity desktop) came with five years.  Whilst yes much of the core of the Lubuntu 16.04 LTS still has two years of support, the LXDE desktop on 16.04 LTS is EOL next month as with MATE, XFCE & other 16.04 flavors.

Comment: If you check http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/ you'll also note not all flavors provided 16.04.6 ISO's  (*contrast with earlier releases; because of the very near EOL date for 16.04 flavors*).

Comment: You're right, the Lubuntu 16.04 Team Support ends April 2019. But I unfortunately can't install the 18.04 version because I haven't the system requirements for it, it's a old computer which I intend to use only offline.

Comment: How old is your machine?, for example a "dell latitude d610 (pentium m, 1gb, intel i915)" is one of my QA test machines for Lubuntu, that has tested many releases up to and including Lubuntu 19.04 [x86/i686 ISO's were only dropped dec-2018]. Another is ibm thinkpad t43..... though your use-case will also dictate machine requirements too.  https://lubuntu.me/xenial-released/ the Lubuntu 16.04  LTS team announcement (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu is no longer [actively] maintained, and lubuntu.net is an unofficial fan site).

Comment: If you used a 16.04.2 or higher ISO for install, you'd be using a HWE (or 18.04) kernel which is all I can think of you trying to avoid by using 16.04.  Anyway https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository is the best *official* info I can find (there are a couple of apt-offline howto's for example https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-or-update-ubuntu-offline-without-internet/).  To get only files needed, I'd probably upload another [*test*] online box [*from same state*] & then use it's /var/cache/apt/archives/ - but I haven't done that in years sorry (*thus don't recall any pitfalls*)

Comment: The machine is very old, with only 375MB of RAM and 1.2GHz AMD 32-bit processor, thus the maximum possible is Lubuntu 16.04 (it will be used offline). Thanks for the help! The apt-offline will be useful.